# How to return a single value for a Prolog "or" operation?

Tags: prolog

I have the following rules in my code:

```
in(rome, lacio).
in(lacio, italy).
in(salvador, bahia).
in(bahia, brazil).

is_in(X, Z) :- (in(X, Y), in(Y, Z)) ; in(X, Z).
```

So if I ask `is_in(rome, lacio).` it will return `true`, which is expected, but if I ask `is_in(rome, italy).` it will return `true` and then `false`, probably because of the second term in `is_in/2`.

What should I do to prevent it for returning the two results and instead return only `true`, like in a normal "or" operation? I though the ";" would take care of it but it didn't worked as I expected.

Comment: This all almost certainly needs to be multiple predicates. Prolog is not like a normal programming language, calling ; or is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best in parts:

```
is_in(X, Z) :- in(X, Z), !, true.
is_in(X, Z) :- in(X, Y), in(Y, Z).
```

But you could also do it with or:

```
is_in(X, Z) :- in(X, Z), !, true; in(X, Y), in (Y, Z).
```

The extra I've added prevents Prolog from branching from that choice-point and returns true, because in this case it is. Do be careful doing this kind of thing though, it can cause problems in larger programs.